# Code Coverage for .NET Standard project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, .net-standard

How do I get code coverage results for .NET Standard projects created with Visual Studio 2017?

- I've tried using the feature that comes with Visual Studio (Menu → Test → Analyze Code Coverage → All tests). That gives me the following report:

  [image]

  **This is not what I expect because**:

  - None of my actual projects are listed, instead I'm only seeing test projects.
  - None of my code in those test projects are listed, instead I'm seeing something called `AutoGeneratedProgram`.
- I've tried using dotCover. It just says that it doesn't support my projects.
- I've tried using OpenCover. It says nothing is covered:

  [image]

Now I've run out of things to try. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the Coverage Result from VS 2017? Did you try the Code Coverage Coloring? You should explain what you expect to get from VS 2017.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I've updated the question.

Comment: OK, so you did expect to see the opposite direction. This is really where the mentioned Code Coverage Coloring comes into the game. Otherwise the concept is to *report how much code is covered by the tests you have written* - which is of course irritating from a TDD point of view because you'd always expect 100% coverage but some code failing the test you have written.

Comment: Can you show some small sample test to make clear which project references you expect to see in your coverage report? I don't have VS 2017 here ATM but I don't expect it to behave much different from VS 2015 here.

Comment: This question only applies to VS 2017. There are no problems with VS 2015. Although, the new .NET Standard project types aren't even supported there afaik.

Comment: I came across this today too. It's still a work in progress, coming in VS 2017, update 3. you can track it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/579

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by adding this to my csproj:

```
<DebugType>Full</DebugType>
```

Comment: If DebugType "Full" makes you nervous, setting DebugType to "dpbonly" also worked for me.

Comment: It makes the project not load in VS2017